# Getting fid attribute and field name in ArcObjects and c#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am new to ArcObjects

[image: Table]

In above attribute table I write query to select "0" in all fields. After I get cursor for looping  selected features.but my problem is I want show the FID number and field name which contain "0" attribute values as a message.

for example I want output like:

( fid ,field name

10,NAME

30,NAME

30,FIRST_CONT.........

)

here mycode

```c#
    ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Application.Document as ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument;
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap map = mxd.FocusMap;
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory wsf= new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace ws= wsf.OpenFromFile(@"D:\ARC OBJECTS", ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace;
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass fcls = fws.OpenFeatureClass("Find_null");
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter qf = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilterClass();
    qf.WhereClause = "FID_1 = 0 OR NAME = '0' OR POPULATION =  0 OR FIRST_CONT = '0'";
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor fcur = fcls.Search(qf, true);
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor cur=fcur as 
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor;

    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRow row= cur.NextRow();
    while (row!=null)
    {
      row= cur.NextRow();
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show exactly what you want as output? NAME// does not exist in any of your rows. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: NAME IS field name.  .....i want fid number, field aliase name

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like below. Here is some VB code and basic idea of logic.

```vb
dim fid... and other variables
pRow = pCursor.NextRow
Do while not pRow is Nothing
  fid1 = pRow.Value(pRow.FindField("FID_1")
  If pRow.Value(pRow.FindField("NAME")) = "0" Then
    bName = True
  End If
  If pRow.Value(pRow.FindField("POPULATION")) = 0 Then
    bPop = True
  End If
  ' Also FIRST_COUNT

  If bName Then
    Debug.Print Cstr(fid) + ",NAME" 
  End If
  If bPop Then
    Debug.Print Cstr(fid) + ",POPULATION"
  End If
  pRow = pCursor.NextRow
Loop
```